# keeping '0.00' from being displayed

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to modify a wordpress plugin to keep it from displaying $0.00 amounts.

original code

```
$gTotal = $foodmenu->getPriceWithLabel();
$html .= '<span class="price">' . $gTotal . '</span>';
$html .= "</div>";
```

This is what i tried so far off reading and searching.

```
$gTotal = $foodmenu->getPriceWithLabel();
$html .= '<span class="price">' . $gTotal === '0.00' ? '-' : $gTotal . '</span>';
$html .= "</div>";
```

Comment: Does `getPriceWithLabel` function return only the amount or amount + label? Try to print it's value and then put the condition.

Comment: just add parenthesis around your subexpression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parenthesis:

```
$html .= '<span class="price">' . ($gTotal === '0.00' ? '-' : $gTotal) . '</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing () on your ternary operator

$html .= '' . ($gTotal === '0.00' ? '-' : $gTotal) . '';